# Maven - Which build phase?

Tags: maven, jetty

I have a Jetty embedded project.
I configured the package phase, using maven-shade-plugin, to create a jar file. It creates a jar file on target folder.

I need to copy some a folter, containing some javascript/html. Which phase do i have to use? the same package phase?

thanks

Comment: Either `prepare-package` or `process-resources` ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you trying to archive - building a `jar` containing ressources such as javascript and html files Maven will automaticially include those resources if you place them under `/src/main/resources` unless excluded in the `pom.xml` in the phase `package` (the same and only non-plugin available phase `package` of the default lifecycle of Maven).

If you on the other hand want to build a webapplication you normally specify the `packaging` to be a `war` leading to a `*.war` web archive. In this case you would normaly place script and html files somewhere under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` as described here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html